# Android how to set custom width on text view row

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

So I have created a layout that is a row of 3 textviews. What I am trying to achieve is to have the first text view a lot wider than the other two text views.

I have tried setting the layout_width to values like 32dp etc but that seems to effect the other text views and the height as well.

So this is what it looks like now 
[image]

and here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colum1"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colum2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colum3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I would Like for possibly textview colum1 to take up the width of the first two text views and the last two to be the widh of one.

Like This 
[image]

Comment: @grrigore that solved my problem Thank you

Comment: your XML is perfect you just change  android:layout_weight="1" to this order.
**For Bigger TextView android:layout_weight="0.4"**
**For Smaller TextView  android:layout_weight="0.2"**
**For Smaller TextView android:layout_weight="0.1"**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colum1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colum2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colum3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#equally-weighted-children).

Answer (score 1):

You will want to remove the weight from the first TextView, either that, or set it's weight to 2. Read more on the Android docs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear

Comment: You might also need to set the layouts "android:weightSum" to 4, if you set the weight of the TextView to 2.